# python refer to parent class from static class

Tags: python, static

Is it possible to access the parent class name within a static class? For example, how to I print the parent class name in the `bar` method below?

```
class Static:
    def bar(self):
        parent_name = ???
        print(parent_name)

class A:
    object = Static()

    def foo(self):
        A.object.bar()

class B:
     object = Static()

    def foo(self):
        B.object.bar()

A().foo()
B().foo()
```

Comment: you might pass `A` to `Static()` likely using a metaclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) method.

It is called on every static attribute of a class when the class is finished constructing. One of the parameters is the "owner" class (A or B), so all you need is to store that reference. Note that this requires a separate Static instance for each parent class, but you're doing that already.

```py
class Static:
    def bar(self):
        print(self.parent_name)

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.parent_name = owner.__name__

class A:
    object = Static()

    def foo(self):
        A.object.bar()

class B:
    object = Static()

    def foo(self):
        B.object.bar()

A().foo()
B().foo()
```

---

I personally avoid these magic methods when possible, so you might also consider taking @JonSG's advice and put the owner class in the `Static` constructor instead. This way the relationship is much clearer, at the cost of adding them after-the-fact.

```py
class Static:
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.parent_name = owner.__name__

    def bar(self):
        print(self.parent_name)

class A:
    def foo(self):
        A.object.bar()
A.object = Static(A)

class B:
    def foo(self):
        B.object.bar()
B.object = Static(B)

A().foo()
B().foo()
```

Alternatively, one might leverage a `metaclass` to do some of the work. This has the potential to also simplify the implementations of `A()` and `B()`

```py
class Static:
    def __init__(self, parent_name) -> None:
        self.parent_name = parent_name

    def bar(self):
        print(self.parent_name)

class AB_Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        cls.object = Static(name)

class A(metaclass=AB_Meta):
    def foo(self):
        A.object.bar()

class B(metaclass=AB_Meta):
    def foo(self):
        B.object.bar()

A().foo()
B().foo()
```

Should give you:

```
A
B
```

Comment: Mind if I add in the implementation with a `metaclass` as a third twist on this?

Comment: Thx! Your first solution works well! But I don't see how your second could since when `Static(A)` or `Static(B)` are called, neither the class `A` nor the class `B` are defined

Comment: Not at all, but I'll also be happy to vote for such an answer. @PinkFloyd My bad, you're right. I've edited the answer to add those attributes *after* the class is constructed. Not as elegant, though.